# How to shutdown OSX and avoid programs inturrupting the shutdown?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, shutdown

There are certain programs that I always run that interrupt the shutdown process. When I try to shut down my laptop a message pops up saying that a program interrupted the shutdown process, but when I check the program it is already shut down. These programs probably just take a little longer to shut down. Is there a good way to shut down OSX without having to deal with these interruptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sudo shutdown -h now` in you terminal. The `shutdown` program sends the `SIGTERM` and after some time `SIGKILL` interrupts to all running programs. So `shutdown` should not be interrupted.

Answer (score 2):

a quick shutdown shortcut is pressing the "control" + "option" + "command" + "eject" buttons simultaneously.

Comment: I thought this was just a shortcut for the usual Restart command (the same one found in the  menu)?

Answer (score 1):

sudo shutdown -h now