# Mac OS X shutdown - is it possible to make it force all programs to quit?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to easily shutdown OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/207228/how-to-easily-shutdown-osx)

Instead of showing the dreaded error message `Application <X> cancelled shutdown`, can I make it always force open programs to quit?

Answer (score 1):

Holding the power button down will turn your computer off quickly if you're in a rush.

or open a terminal window and type 'sudo shutdown -h now' and enter password. Done.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Will it not damage components?

Comment: The only thing this should affect would be unsaved data. mac osx has safeguards against damaging hardware built in.

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird The operating system has safeguards that prevent a hardware reset from damaging hardware? What?